# Compiling Zurb Foundation 6 with Laravel's Elixir (Gulp)

Tags: laravel, sass, gulp, homestead, zurb-foundation-6

So I'm trying to pull in and compile Foundation 6 in my Laravel project but I seem to be missing something from my gulpfile.js in order for it to work as expected.

### First I download the package using

> bower install foundation-sites --save

No problem.

Then I have this in my gulpfile.js

```
elixir(function(mix) {


mix.sass(
    '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/**/*.scss'
);


mix.copy(
    'resources/assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'public/js/jquery.min.js'
);

mix.copy(
    'resources/assets/bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js',
    'public/js/foundation.min.js'
);

mix.copy(
    'resources/assets/bower_components/what-input/what-input.min.js',
    'public/js/what-input.min.js'
);
```

});

(Yeah, I know I can combine the copy commands and I will.)

When I run gulp everything looks good.

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Kreddat$ gulp
[14:34:42] Using gulpfile ~/Code/Kreddat/gulpfile.js
[14:34:42] Starting 'default'...
[14:34:42] Starting 'sass'...

Fetching Sass Source Files...
  - resources/assets/bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/**/*.scss


Saving To...
   - public/css/app.css

[14:34:44] Finished 'default' after 1.61 s
[14:34:44] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compiled!
[14:34:44] Finished 'sass' after 2.38 s
[14:34:44] Starting 'copy'...

Fetching Copy Source Files...
   - resources/assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js


Saving To...
   - public/js/jquery.min.js

[14:34:44] Finished 'copy' after 28 ms
[14:34:44] Starting 'copy'...

Fetching Copy Source Files...
   - resources/assets/bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js


Saving To...
   - public/js/foundation.min.js

[14:34:44] Finished 'copy' after 24 ms
[14:34:44] Starting 'copy'...

Fetching Copy Source Files...
   - resources/assets/bower_components/what-input/what-input.min.js


Saving To...
   - public/js/what-input.min.js

[14:34:44] Finished 'copy' after 18 ms
[14:34:44] Starting 'copy'...
```

However, when I use the generated CSS in a HTML file it looks a bit weird:

[image: site looking weird]

When I change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" type="text/css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.1/css/foundation.css" type="text/css">` however everything looks great:

[image: site looking great]

This leads me to believe that I'm doing something wrong when including the Sass files in my gulpfile.js. Any ideas on how to get my compiled CSS to match the distributed version?

UPDATE #1
This is what I have in my gulpfile.js at the moment but the result is the same - page still looks weird.

```
    mix.sass([
    '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss',
    '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/_global.scss',
    '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/**/*.scss',
    'app.scss'
], 'public/css/app.css');
```

Comment: Sorry this sentence: "When I change to however everything looks great:" should read:

    When I change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" type="text/css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.0.1/css/foundation.css" type="text/css">` however everything looks great:

Answer (score 6):

Solved it!

In my gulpfile.js:

```
    mix.sass(
    'app.scss',
    'public/css/app.css',
    { includePaths:
        ['resources/assets/bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/']
    });
```

In my app.scss:

```
@import 'foundation';
@include foundation-everything;
```

Done!

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same problem, the step i was skipping was adding the line `@include foundation-everything;` .

As a little extra tip, the problem itself was that everything was compiling fine, but since there was no `@include foundation-everything` nothing was being added to the `app.css` file (Other than the Foundation comment in `foundation.scss`).

Answer (score 1):

Yea. I had a play at this the other day but with NPM. Basically you have to include all the SASS components you want and then the settings.

So in your app.scss have

```
// app.scss
@include "settings";
@charset 'utf-8';

@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation';
@import 'motion-ui';

@include foundation-global-styles;
@include foundation-grid;
@include foundation-typography;
@include foundation-button;
@include foundation-forms;
@include foundation-visibility-classes;
@include foundation-float-classes;
@include foundation-accordion;
@include foundation-badge;
@include foundation-breadcrumbs;
@include foundation-button-group;
@include foundation-callout;
@include foundation-close-button;
@include foundation-drilldown-menu;
@include foundation-dropdown;
@include foundation-dropdown-menu;
@include foundation-flex-video;
@include foundation-label;
@include foundation-media-object;
@include foundation-menu;
@include foundation-off-canvas;
@include foundation-orbit;
@include foundation-pagination;
@include foundation-progress-bar;
@include foundation-slider;
@include foundation-sticky;
@include foundation-reveal;
@include foundation-switch;
@include foundation-table;
@include foundation-tabs;
@include foundation-thumbnail;
@include foundation-title-bar;
@include foundation-tooltip;
@include foundation-top-bar;

@include motion-ui-transitions;
@include motion-ui-animations;
```

Then create a _settings.scss file and include that in your app.scss file. You will then need all this.

```
//  Foundation for Sites Settings
//  -----------------------------
//
//  Table of Contents:
//
//   1. Global
//   2. Breakpoints
//   3. The Grid
//   4. Base Typography
//   5. Typography Helpers
//   6. Abide
//   7. Accordion
//   8. Accordion Menu
//   9. Badge
//  10. Breadcrumbs
//  11. Button
//  12. Button Group
//  13. Callout
//  14. Close Button
//  15. Drilldown
//  16. Dropdown
//  17. Dropdown Menu
//  18. Flex Video
//  19. Forms
//  20. Label
//  21. Media Object
//  22. Menu
//  23. Off-canvas
//  24. Orbit
//  25. Pagination
//  26. Progress Bar
//  27. Reveal
//  28. Slider
//  29. Switch
//  30. Table
//  31. Tabs
//  32. Thumbnail
//  33. Tooltip
//  34. Top Bar

@import 'util/util';

// 1. Global
// ---------

$global-width: rem-calc(1200);
$global-font-size: 100%;
$global-lineheight: 1.5;
$primary-color: #2199e8;
$secondary-color: #777;
$success-color: #3adb76;
$warning-color: #ffae00;
$alert-color: #ec5840;
$light-gray: #e6e6e6;
$medium-gray: #cacaca;
$dark-gray: #8a8a8a;
$black: #0a0a0a;
$white: #fefefe;
$body-background: $white;
$body-font-color: $black;
$body-font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
$body-antialiased: true;
$global-margin: 1rem;
$global-padding: 1rem;
$global-margin: 1rem;
$global-weight-normal: normal;
$global-weight-bold: bold;
$global-radius: 0;
$global-text-direction: ltr;
$rem-base: 16px;

// 2. Breakpoints
// --------------

$breakpoints: (
  small: 0,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1200px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
);
$breakpoint-classes: (small medium large);

// 3. The Grid
// -----------

$grid-row-width: $global-width;
$grid-column-count: 12;
$grid-column-gutter: 30px;
$block-grid-max: 6;

// 4. Base Typography
// ------------------

$header-font-family: $body-font-family;
$header-font-weight: $global-weight-normal;
$header-font-style: normal;
$font-family-monospace: Consolas, 'Liberation Mono', Courier, monospace;
$header-sizes: (
  small: (
    'h1': 24,
    'h2': 20,
    'h3': 19,
    'h4': 18,
    'h5': 17,
    'h6': 16,
  ),
  medium: (
    'h1': 48,
    'h2': 40,
    'h3': 31,
    'h4': 25,
    'h5': 20,
    'h6': 16,
  ),
);
$header-color: inherit;
$header-lineheight: 1.4;
$header-margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
$header-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
$small-font-size: 80%;
$header-small-font-color: $medium-gray;
$paragraph-lineheight: 1.6;
$paragraph-margin-bottom: 1rem;
$paragraph-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
$code-color: $black;
$code-font-family: $font-family-monospace;
$code-font-weight: $global-weight-normal;
$code-background: $light-gray;
$code-border: 1px solid $medium-gray;
$code-padding: rem-calc(2 5 1);
$anchor-color: $primary-color;
$anchor-color-hover: scale-color($anchor-color, $lightness: -14%);
$anchor-text-decoration: none;
$anchor-text-decoration-hover: none;
$hr-width: $global-width;
$hr-border: 1px solid $medium-gray;
$hr-margin: rem-calc(20) auto;
$list-lineheight: $paragraph-lineheight;
$list-margin-bottom: $paragraph-margin-bottom;
$list-style-type: disc;
$list-style-position: outside;
$list-side-margin: 1.25rem;
$list-nested-side-margin: 1.25rem;
$defnlist-margin-bottom: 1rem;
$defnlist-term-weight: $global-weight-bold;
$defnlist-term-margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
$blockquote-color: $dark-gray;
$blockquote-padding: rem-calc(9 20 0 19);
$blockquote-border: 1px solid $medium-gray;
$cite-font-size: rem-calc(13);
$cite-color: $dark-gray;
$keystroke-font: $font-family-monospace;
$keystroke-color: $black;
$keystroke-background: $light-gray;
$keystroke-padding: rem-calc(2 4 0);
$keystroke-radius: $global-radius;
$abbr-underline: 1px dotted $black;

// 5. Typography Helpers
// ---------------------

$lead-font-size: $global-font-size * 1.25;
$lead-lineheight: 1.6;
$subheader-lineheight: 1.4;
$subheader-color: $dark-gray;
$subheader-font-weight: $global-weight-normal;
$subheader-margin-top: 0.2rem;
$subheader-margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
$stat-font-size: 2.5rem;

// 6. Abide
// --------

$abide-inputs: true;
$abide-labels: true;
$input-background-invalid: $alert-color;
$form-label-color-invalid: $alert-color;
$input-error-color: $alert-color;
$input-error-font-size: rem-calc(12);
$input-error-font-weight: $global-weight-bold;

// 7. Accordion
// ------------

$accordion-background: $white;
$accordion-plusminus: true;
$accordion-item-color: foreground($accordion-background, $primary-color);
$accordion-item-background-hover: $light-gray;
$accordion-item-padding: 1.25rem 1rem;
$accordion-content-background: $white;
$accordion-content-border: 1px solid $light-gray;
$accordion-content-color: foreground($accordion-background, $primary-color);
$accordion-content-padding: 1rem;

// 8. Accordion Menu
// -----------------

$accordionmenu-arrows: true;

// 9. Badge
// --------

$badge-background: $primary-color;
$badge-color: foreground($badge-background);
$badge-padding: 0.3em;
$badge-minwidth: 2.1em;
$badge-font-size: 0.6rem;

// 10. Breadcrumbs
// ---------------

$breadcrumbs-margin: 0 0 $global-margin 0;
$breadcrumbs-item-font-size: rem-calc(11);
$breadcrumbs-item-color: $primary-color;
$breadcrumbs-item-color-current: $black;
$breadcrumbs-item-color-disabled: $medium-gray;
$breadcrumbs-item-margin: 0.75rem;
$breadcrumbs-item-uppercase: true;
$breadcrumbs-item-slash: true;

// 11. Button
// ----------

$button-padding: 0.85em 1em;
$button-margin: 0 $global-margin $global-margin 0;
$button-fill: solid;
$button-background: $primary-color;
$button-background-hover: scale-color($button-background, $lightness: -15%);
$button-color: #fff;
$button-color-alt: #000;
$button-radius: $global-radius;
$button-sizes: (
  tiny: 0.6rem,
  small: 0.75rem,
  default: 0.9rem,
  large: 1.25rem,
);
$button-opacity-disabled: 0.25;

// 12. Button Group
// ----------------

$buttongroup-margin: 1rem;
$buttongroup-spacing: 1px;
$buttongroup-child-selector: '.button';
$buttongroup-expand-max: 6;

// 13. Callout
// -----------

$callout-background: $white;
$callout-background-fade: 85%;
$callout-border: 1px solid rgba($black, 0.25);
$callout-margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
$callout-padding: 1rem;
$callout-font-color: $body-font-color;
$callout-font-color-alt: $body-background;
$callout-radius: $global-radius;
$callout-link-tint: 30%;

// 14. Close Button
// ----------------

$closebutton-position: right top;
$closebutton-offset-horizontal: 1rem;
$closebutton-offset-vertical: 0.5rem;
$closebutton-size: 2em;
$closebutton-lineheight: 1;
$closebutton-color: $dark-gray;
$closebutton-color-hover: $black;

// 15. Drilldown
// -------------

$drilldown-transition: transform 0.15s linear;
$drilldown-arrows: true;

// 16. Dropdown
// ------------

$dropdown-padding: 1rem;
$dropdown-border: 1px solid $medium-gray;
$dropdown-font-size: 16rem;
$dropdown-width: 300px;
$dropdown-radius: $global-radius;
$dropdown-sizes: (
  tiny: 100px,
  small: 200px,
  large: 400px,
);

// 17. Dropdown Menu
// -----------------

$dropdownmenu-arrows: true;
$dropdownmenu-min-width: 200px;
$dropdownmenu-background: $white;
$dropdownmenu-border: 1px solid $medium-gray;

// 18. Flex Video
// --------------

$flexvideo-padding-top: rem-calc(25);
$flexvideo-margin-bottom: rem-calc(16);
$flexvideo-ratio: 4 by 3;
$flexvideo-ratio-widescreen: 16 by 9;

// 19. Forms
// ---------

$fieldset-border: 1px solid $medium-gray;
$fieldset-padding: rem-calc(20);
$fieldset-margin: rem-calc(18 0);
$legend-padding: rem-calc(0 3);
$form-spacing: rem-calc(16);
$helptext-color: #333;
$helptext-font-size: rem-calc(13);
$helptext-font-style: italic;
$input-prefix-color: $black;
$input-prefix-background: $light-gray;
$input-prefix-border: 1px solid $medium-gray;
$input-prefix-padding: 1rem;
$form-label-color: $black;
$form-label-font-size: rem-calc(14);
$form-label-font-weight: $global-weight-normal;
$form-label-line-height: 1.8;
$select-background: #fafafa;
$select-triangle-color: #333;
$select-radius: $global-radius;
$input-color: $dark-gray;
$input-font-family: inherit;
$input-font-size: rem-calc(16);
$input-background: $white;
$input-background-focus: $white;
$input-background-disabled: $light-gray;
$input-border: 1px solid $medium-gray;
$input-border-focus: 1px solid $dark-gray;
$input-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba($black, 0.1);
$input-shadow-focus: 0 0 5px $medium-gray;
$input-cursor-disabled: default;
$input-transition: box-shadow 0.5s, border-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
$input-number-spinners: true;
$input-radius: $global-radius;

// 20. Label
// ---------

$label-background: $primary-color;
$label-color: foreground($label-background);
$label-font-size: 0.8rem;
$label-padding: 0.33333rem 0.5rem;
$label-radius: $global-radius;

// 21. Media Object
// ----------------

$mediaobject-margin-bottom: $global-margin;
$mediaobject-section-padding: $global-padding;
$mediaobject-image-width-stacked: 100%;

// 22. Menu
// --------

$menu-margin: 0;
$menu-margin-nested: 1rem;
$menu-item-padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
$menu-icon-spacing: 0.25rem;
$menu-expand-max: 6;

// 23. Off-canvas
// --------------

$offcanvas-size: 250px;
$offcanvas-background: $light-gray;
$offcanvas-zindex: -1;
$offcanvas-transition-length: 0.5s;
$offcanvas-transition-timing: ease;
$offcanvas-fixed-reveal: true;
$offcanvas-exit-background: rgba($white, 0.25);
$maincontent-class: 'off-canvas-content';
$maincontent-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba($black, 0.5);

// 24. Orbit
// ---------

$orbit-bullet-background: $medium-gray;
$orbit-bullet-background-active: $dark-gray;
$orbit-bullet-diameter: 1.2rem;
$orbit-bullet-margin: 0.1rem;
$orbit-bullet-margin-top: 0.8rem;
$orbit-bullet-margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
$orbit-caption-background: rgba($black, 0.5);
$orbit-caption-padding: 1rem;
$orbit-control-background-hover: rgba($black, 0.5);
$orbit-control-padding: 1rem;
$orbit-control-zindex: 10;

// 25. Pagination
// --------------

$pagination-font-size: rem-calc(14);
$pagination-margin-bottom: $global-margin;
$pagination-item-color: $black;
$pagination-item-padding: rem-calc(3 10);
$pagination-item-spacing: rem-calc(1);
$pagination-radius: $global-radius;
$pagination-item-background-hover: $light-gray;
$pagination-item-background-current: $primary-color;
$pagination-item-color-current: foreground($pagination-item-background-current);
$pagination-item-color-disabled: $medium-gray;
$pagination-ellipsis-color: $black;
$pagination-mobile-items: false;
$pagination-arrows: true;

// 26. Progress Bar
// ----------------

$progress-height: 1rem;
$progress-background: $medium-gray;
$progress-margin-bottom: $global-margin;
$progress-meter-background: $primary-color;
$progress-radius: $global-radius;

// 27. Reveal
// ----------

$reveal-background: $white;
$reveal-width: 600px;
$reveal-max-width: $global-width;
$reveal-offset: rem-calc(100);
$reveal-padding: $global-padding;
$reveal-border: 1px solid $medium-gray;
$reveal-radius: $global-radius;
$reveal-zindex: 1005;
$reveal-overlay-background: rgba($black, 0.45);

// 28. Slider
// ----------

$slider-height: 0.5rem;
$slider-width-vertical: $slider-height;
$slider-background: $light-gray;
$slider-fill-background: $medium-gray;
$slider-handle-height: 1.4rem;
$slider-handle-width: 1.4rem;
$slider-handle-background: $primary-color;
$slider-opacity-disabled: 0.25;
$slider-radius: $global-radius;
$slider-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

// 29. Switch
// ----------

$switch-background: $medium-gray;
$switch-background-active: $primary-color;
$switch-height: 2rem;
$switch-height-tiny: 1.5rem;
$switch-height-small: 1.75rem;
$switch-height-large: 2.5rem;
$switch-radius: $global-radius;
$switch-margin: $global-margin;
$switch-paddle-background: $white;
$switch-paddle-offset: 0.25rem;
$switch-paddle-radius: $global-radius;
$switch-paddle-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;

// 30. Table
// ---------

$table-background: $white;
$table-color-scale: 5%;
$table-border: 1px solid smart-scale($table-background, $table-color-scale);
$table-padding: rem-calc(8 10 10);
$table-hover-scale: 2%;
$table-row-hover: darken($table-background, $table-hover-scale);
$table-row-stripe-hover: darken($table-background, $table-color-scale + $table-hover-scale);
$table-striped-background: smart-scale($table-background, $table-color-scale);
$table-stripe: even;
$table-head-background: smart-scale($table-background, $table-color-scale / 2);
$table-foot-background: smart-scale($table-background, $table-color-scale);
$table-head-font-color: $body-font-color;
$show-header-for-stacked: false;

// 31. Tabs
// --------

$tab-margin: 0;
$tab-background: $white;
$tab-background-active: $light-gray;
$tab-border: $light-gray;
$tab-item-color: foreground($tab-background, $primary-color);
$tab-item-background-hover: $white;
$tab-item-padding: 1.25rem 1.5rem;
$tab-expand-max: 6;
$tab-content-background: $white;
$tab-content-border: $light-gray;
$tab-content-color: foreground($tab-background, $primary-color);
$tab-content-padding: 1rem;

// 32. Thumbnail
// -------------

$thumbnail-border: solid 4px $white;
$thumbnail-margin-bottom: $global-margin;
$thumbnail-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba($black, 0.2);
$thumbnail-shadow-hover: 0 0 6px 1px rgba($primary-color, 0.5);
$thumbnail-transition: box-shadow 200ms ease-out;
$thumbnail-radius: $global-radius;

// 33. Tooltip
// -----------

$tooltip-background-color: $black;
$tooltip-color: $white;
$tooltip-padding: 0.75rem;
$tooltip-font-size: $small-font-size;
$tooltip-pip-width: 0.75rem;
$tooltip-pip-height: $tooltip-pip-width * 0.866;
$tooltip-pip-offset: 1.25rem;
$tooltip-radius: $global-radius;

// 34. Top Bar
// -----------

$topbar-padding: 0.5rem;
$topbar-background: #eee;
$topbar-link-color: #fff;
$topbar-input-width: 200px;
```

Comment: Currently I have this in my gulpfile.js but it still looks the same when I render the page. 

        mix.sass([
        '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss',
        '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/_global.scss',
        '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/**/*.scss',
        'app.scss'
    ], 'public/css/app.css');